# Drag-And-Drop Drag Mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, mouseover

I got this drag and drop javascript, which is being used by placing furniture in a room. [Watch on my website here.](http://lolk3070.dk/roomtest/index.html)
I want to make so while dragging the furniture over the floor (each tile), the tile you got your mouseover will change image (Just like a mouseover/hover works). How do I make this in javascript while dragging?

**This is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div2').on("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var temp = null;
  if(ev.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){
    temp = $(ev.target);
    $(ev.target).parent().empty().append(document.getElementById(data));
    $('#div3 #div1').append(temp);
  }
  else
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

$(document).on("click", "#tapetsmall", function(){
   document.getElementById("walls").src="http://i.imgur.com/Ptv1Lnh.png";
});
```

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

#floor {
  top:116px;
  left:393px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 65px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/tCuykFV.png")
}

#floor img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12;
}

#div3 {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#dice {
    width:56px;
    height:79px;
}

#walls {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:688px;
  height:338px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<img id="walls" src="http://i.imgur.com/GA3vVPI.png">

<!-- Row Floor 1 -->

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:122px;left:392px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:138px;left:360px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:154px;left:328px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:170px;left:296px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:186px;left:264px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:202px;left:232px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:218px;left:200px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:234px;left:168px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:250px;left:136px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:266px;left:104px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:282px;left:72px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:298px;left:40px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:314px;left:8px;"></div>

<!-- Row Floor 2 -->

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:138px;left:424px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:154px;left:392px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:170px;left:360px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:186px;left:328px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:202px;left:296px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:218px;left:264px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:234px;left:232px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:250px;left:200px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:266px;left:168px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:282px;left:136px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:298px;left:104px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:314px;left:72px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:330px;left:40px;"></div>

<!-- Row Floor 3 -->

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:154px;left:456px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:170px;left:424px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:186px;left:392px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:202px;left:360px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:218px;left:328px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:234px;left:296px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:250px;left:264px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:266px;left:232px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:282px;left:200px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:298px;left:168px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:314px;left:136px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:330px;left:104px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:346px;left:72px;"></div>

<!-- Row Floor 4 -->

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:170px;left:488px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:186px;left:456px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:202px;left:424px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:218px;left:392px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:234px;left:360px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:250px;left:328px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:266px;left:296px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:282px;left:264px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:298px;left:232px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:314px;left:200px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:330px;left:168px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:346px;left:136px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:362px;left:104px;"></div>

<!-- Row Floor 5 -->

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:186px;left:520px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:202px;left:488px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:218px;left:456px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:234px;left:424px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:250px;left:392px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:266px;left:360px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:282px;left:328px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:298px;left:296px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:314px;left:264px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:330px;left:232px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:346px;left:200px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:362px;left:168px;"></div>

<div id="floor" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="top:378px;left:136px;"></div>



<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/habbo.gamepedia.com/e/ed/Edicehc.png?version=6e01ba71341b8361df23749c65498f44" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="56" height="79">
  
  <img src="https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/habbo.gamepedia.com/0/0f/Mocchamaster.png?version=6cf4d970f845287fa21d4ef7691eee84" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="66" height="137">
  
  <img src="https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/habbo.gamepedia.com/8/8f/Club_sofa.png?version=376411c6afa6472a40f9495e18c51ceb" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="clubsofa" width="113" height="85" >
  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tBWoRg6.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="tapetsmall" width="32" height="32" >
  
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a `background-image` for each floor tile you could take the same image that was given and change the color to what you want it be when the mouse is over that tile. Then change the image back to what it originally was when the mouse leaves that tile.

In your JS file you could then do something like the below:

```
var floorTiles = document.querySelectorAll("#floor");

for(var i = 0; i < floorTiles.length; i++){ 
  floorTiles[i].ondragover = function(ev) { 
    if (ev.target.id === "floor") {
      ev.target.style.backgroundImage = "https://i.imgur.com/vQ70H33.png"; 
    }
  }; 
  floorTiles[i].ondragleave = function(ev) { 
    if (ev.target.id === "floor") {
      ev.target.style.backgroundImage = "https://i.imgur.com/tCuykFV.png"; 
    }
  };
}
```

The way the above code works is it dynamically grabs everything in the Document Object Model (DOM) using `querySelectorAll` and puts it into a NodeList of elements. We then iterate over the list and attach event listeners for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` which run when the pointer goes over the element and when the pointer leaves the element. When the pointer leaves the element you just want to set the `backgroundImage` back to the original image.

EDIT: I edited the above code to replace the background image. Since you already have an `ondragover` attached to all of your floor tiles you need to put this code somewhere in the function `allowDrop(event)`. It should highlight your tiles when you drag over them as well. You can leave the mouse enter and mouse leave code since this changes the tile when your mouse passes over those tiles. It's just different when you're dragging something. Hope this helps!

Comment: You got example of it with a backgroundImage? Because I tried this, but it doesn't work when i try BackgroundImage? I might be writing it the wrong way?

Comment: Please post the link of the of the first image you use for mouseover here. @Disko

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with the working backgroundImage bro? :)

Comment: @Disko happily, I just need the image you want it to be on hover. I already have the original tile image I just need the new one and a link to it.

Comment: Okay, 2 seconds! :)

Comment: I see what you mean now, you want the tile to light up when you drag that image over it. Not just when the mouse goes over it. You could do this using strictly JS, but as opposed to reinventing the wheel I personally would rather use http://interactjs.io/

Comment: With strict JS you could also do what is in my answer, notice the new edit.

Comment: It's not something you can make in a fiddle bro? :/

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this when you drag the furni over a tile, the tile should change backgroundimage, looking like this [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjJKy.png) (Made in photoshop)